# System-wide config of gem operations?

Tags: macos

The answer to just about everything gem related on El Capitan -- including installing fastlane -- for me has been using this switch `-n /usr/local/bin`

(So `sudo gem install fastlane` fails but `sudo gem -n /usr/local/bin install fastlane` works.)

How can I apply this to all gem operations automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32253142/8047).

In your `~/.gemrc` put the single line

```
gem: -n/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Isn't there a space missing between `-n` and `/usr/lo...` or does it work like this?

Comment: @klanomath empirically, it works. I also think that it would work on the command line like this, and many flags do not actually need a space (I think), because the ones that are words usually have two dashes like `--version`

Answer (score 1):

Because El Capitan introduction to SIP (System Integrity Protection) you need to change your `GEM_HOME` or do similar something like `sudo gem install bundler -n /usr/local/bin`.